# How to detect when and if a deleteable Google Realtime IndexReference is deleted?

Tags: google-drive-api, collaboration, google-drive-realtime-api

If a non-deletable Google Realtime IndexReference is created:

```
myIndexRef = myCollabList.registerReference (10, false);

  or

myIndexRef = myCollabString.registerReference (20, false);
```

then when its 'container' is deleted, the IndexReference is shifted, and generates a ReferenceShiftedEvent.

But if it's deletable:

```
myIndexRef = myCollabList.registerReference (10, true);
```

How should or could its deletion be detected? There is no explicit event covering this in the Google Realtime API, nor an isDeleted property or similar.

Each user could track changes to both the containing string or list, and also shifts of each IndexReference, listen for ValuesRemovedEvents or TextDeletedEvents, and thus *infer* an IndexReference's deletion, but it seems a trouble-prone way to do it, and puts the burden in the wrong place if those IndexReferences are other collaborators' edit carets, for instance... One user could easily find they have a reference to an IndexReference which has been subsequently deleted.

By extension, if the IndexReferences are in a map within the model, what happens to the map when one is deleted?

Comment: Do you not get a reference shifted event when the index reference is deleted?  In effect, it gets shifted to position -1 and then stays there forever. If it's in a map, the object will still be there.  I think you could manually set it to a new location.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for that and try it.